# Custom formula is: Range = TRUE, Google sheets, Conditional format,

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Im trying to write a custom formula that does this:
Imagine a Row with 2 empty cells following 4 check-boxes. Unticked=`FALSE`, Ticked= `TRUE`
[image]
If any of the boxes are ticked **ONLY** `A1` **AND** `B1` will turn red.

---

My current best is that `A1` OR `B1` will turn red if relatively `C1` OR `D1` are TRUE, OR when only one of the checkbox cells is defined.
Sadly defining range `C$1:F$1 = TRUE` doesn't do the trick.

I added @basic help to my sheet but am encountering a new problem.
[image]
**Do not mark the whole range like this!**

```
=OR($C1:$G8)
```

**Only the corresponding row.**

```
=OR($C1:$G1)
```

Solved!

Comment: Change $G8 to $G1.

Comment: @basic Yes ofcource. I only want the first two columns to react to the same row, not the whole row. You are the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
=OR($C1:$F1)
```

apply to range `A:B`

[image]

#### Reference:

- [OR function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en)

Comment: Edited original post. Got a new problem.